# Strangeness with a view controller's frame

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've created a simple application with a single view controller and removed the status bar so I can use the full height of the screen. The view controller's xib file loads perfectly well, displaying a backdrop image very nicely. I then added a custom view object which will be handling certain graphical tasks directly for me, and asked it to initialize itself with the custom view's frame rectangle. I did this in the 'viewDidLoad' method for the view controller. For some strange reason though, the view controller is reporting its frame rectangle as if the status bar were still visible, despite the fact that I hide it before creating the view controller. Can someone explain why, and maybe suggest a workaround?

-Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, it's always the simple things isn't it? I just forgot this command:
viewHolder.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;